# Debian 8: Shell "service" command works quietly

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I reinstalled `Debian 8 Jessie` on my vserver recently.

I noticed an anomaly to previous versions: The `service` command shows no confirmation message anymore. If I want to restart e.g. the `ssh` service with `$ service ssh restart` it prints no confirmation message, that it actually does something. But if I type `$ /etc/init.d/ssh restart` it shows properly the message:

```
[ok] Restarting ssh ....
```

So is this in error in my Debian system or is this normal ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: Debian uses systemd now...

Comment: Did it fail? Or did it work silently?  It's supposed to work according to https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Integration

Comment: @Mikel Well it obviously works silently, but i'd like to have a kind of feedback of the task after the command, whether it's service or systemds "systemctl". Do i have the possibility to get a confirmation message after the command ?

Comment: That's not what your question originally said. ;)

Comment: Hence i edited the title of my question.

Comment: Looks like `service restart` just does `systemctl restart`, which runs silently per http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.systemd.devel/7246.  If you need something else, consider filing a feature request for the [sysvinit package](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/sysvinit).